# How can I get taskID from a specific project on Workfront?

Tags: workfront-api

I tried to use this:

> https://{CompanyTenant}.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/task/search?{FieldName}={FieldValue}&apiKey={APIKey}&projectID={projectID}

Get Error!

> my point is to find a {taskID} that has a given {FieldValue} on the
>   specific {FieldName}.

Answer (score 0):

Is FieldName a custom field or a system field? If it's the latter, that query should work, but if it's the former, you'll need to search for DE:{FieldName} as it's a Data Extension field.

Comment: This field is a custom field. I already tried using your advice but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @PrachaChuacharoensiri Can you provide more details? What do you mean it doesn't work? Are you getting an error or no results?